# What is the best way to manage pages content?

Tags: page-template

My current template has the "onepage" style, but for SEO questions I've decided to change all theme by using pages separately in order to optimize each page and enjoy the best of Yoast plugin.

In my "onepage" template, I use get_template_part to include every section into the homepage. Every section is a category and each content is a post. Every "template part" contains a custom WP_Query I use to get the content.

Now I'm going to use multiple pages, I'm a little bit lost about managing the content. Should I insert all html of each section into the WP editor or it's better to create a custom template (e.g. page-about.php) and put html there? I mean, is it a good pratice using posts to manage content for pages or it's not a recommended way?

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you to use WP default editor functionality to display HTML on front end until and unless you don't have any specific requirement for a specific page. This will be easy for you to manage easily.

Comment: Yes, actually that's what I kept in mind, but the point is I will gone have to type html tags manually, but for SEO it would be better, I guess...